# Inject HTML into div via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, jira

I am trying to get onclick/onfocus/onchange in an HTML tag that is being created by Jira. The item itself is a drop down list and while I can get onfocus to work on other IDs, I cant get it to work on the drop down list

What I have:

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
console.log("Testing");
var colorDropDown = document.getElementById('someID');

function changeColor()
{
    //if(value)
    alert("Hello World");
}

document.getElementById("someID").innerHTML ="<onfocus=\"changeColor()\"></select>"
//document.getElementById("customfield_11901").innerHTML = "<select class=\"select cf-select\" name=\"customfield_11901\" id=\"customfield_11901\" onfocus=\"changeColor()\">"

</script>
```

After using innerHTML, the onfocus does not appear in the page. I have also tried this by copying the entire tag and inputting it via HTML.

I have used the .onchange function after getElementById, but that does not work either.

Comment: `<onfocus>` isn't a thing.

Comment: `<onfocus=\"changeColor()\"></select>` isn't valid HTML. Do you mean `<select onfocus=\"changeColor()\"></select>`?

Comment: you don't need to inject html to add an event listener, is there a reason you're on that path?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek yes, that is what I meant, I will give that try.

Comment: @aw04 I am just trying things I am seeing as a solution. I will try other things as I find them or as they are suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the .attr() function under jQuery:

```
$('#select_id').attr('onfocus', 'changeColor();');
```

Or you can use the addEventListener with plain JS:

```
object = document.getElementById('#select_id');
object.addEventListener('focus', 'changeColor();');
```

Comment: I gave this a try and I didnt work at first, but I googled the addEventListener function and made my string look like this:

    testObject=addEventListener('change', function(){colorChange();},false)

This ended up working out for me. Thank you very much!